# xfinium pdf unicode font not work in android in a Xamarin forms application

Tags: pdf, xamarin, unicode, xamarin.forms, pdf-generation

I've been spinning my wheels on this subject for a few days. I have Xfinium PDF in a Xamarin.Forms application I'm working on and I need to generate a pdf in different languages. So I have different .otf files set up as a PdfUnicodeTrueTypeFont. Now this works in iOS no problem, but in Android the PDF is generated blank if I try to generate it in a language that needs one of these fonts. I also have lost the ability due some other things going on in my work environment to side load to android or debug in android at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the font is embedded in the PDF (either by looking at the file directly or using an application to get information on embedded fonts).

If the font is not embedded it's possible that Android is failing to fallback to another font for some reason. Does the PDF open correctly Chrome?

Comment: I found the issue was that the app was wrapped by Citrix and the functionality for displaying unicode was removed by them when they wrap the app.